Nand2Tetris - the A register is overwritten?
when we write @address, the A register is overwritten? for example I'm trying to write the assembly for , pop local 2 , but i dont sure that its a good way:
@LCL
D=M
@2 
A=D+A
@13
M=A // LOCAL[2] IS INSIDE REGISTER 13
D=A
@SP
AM=M-1
D=M
@13
A=M//GOING LOCAL[2]
M=D//STORE WHAT WAS AT THE TOP OF THE STACK


Looks like there's lots of extra stuff there that isn't part of pop local 2.  Suggest to start by writing out in simple pseudo code exactly what pop local 2 should mean for your clarity.  What happens to local 2?  What happens to the SP?  What memory is read and what is written.  This should clearly answer questions like "Are you trying to read local 2, write it, or both?".  As far as I can tell, your code is writing local 2 (@13; M=A), then reading local 2 (@13; A=M), then writing it again (M=D).  If you don't find these in your pseudo code, then they shouldn't appear in your assembly.

Yes, @ is an immediate load into the A register. Dealing with the limited number of actual registers in the physical hardware is part of the challenge.
Some techniques that may be useful to you:

The ability to store into multiple destinations (as you do in AM=M-1) can be particularly handy; I think you missed the chance to fold M=A,D=A into MD=A.

When adding 2 to D, D=D+1,D=D+1 is as fast as @2,D=D+A but preserves A. (Side note: in your code, you're doing A=D+A and then immediately overwriting it with @13; is this correct?). Depending on the situation, it can be worth using longer D=D+1 sequences to avoid having to reload A. Same thing goes for A=A+1 sequences; they preserve D.

Reordering operations can sometimes save you instructions, particularly if you can stash something in D and compute an address entirely in A.


If I am not mistaken (and I may well be, it's the middle of the night and I have insomnia), you can implement POP Local 2 in 8 instructions.
